# Spring JPA query returns multiple copies of the same entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities in my project User and Order, they are linked as ManyToOne, when I'm trying to get all Users with specific Order status I get multiple copies of the same User. What am I doing wrong here?

User.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "t_user")
public class User {
    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    Set<Order> orders = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Order.java

```
public class Order {
    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "order_status", nullable = false)
    OrderStatus orderStatus;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    public void addUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
        user.getOrders().add(this);
    }

    public void removeUser() {
        if (user != null) {
            user.getOrders().remove(this);
            this.user = null;
        }
    }
}
```

OrderStatus.java

```
public enum OrderStatus {
    PAYMENT, PAID, CAR_IN_USE, CAR_RETURNED, CLOSED;
}
```

UserDao.java

```
@Repository
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User, UUID> {
    Page<User> findAllByOrders_OrderStatus(OrderStatus orderStatus, Pageable pageable);
}
```

findAllByOrders_OrderStatus always return multiple copies of User (if I have 6 orders, I'll have 6 User copies). What should I change here?

Comment: Try using `findDistinctByOrders_OrderStatus`

Comment: Thank you, Eric. It helped, I think it works as I wanted now.